# What is the correct story of Sukha Brahmarishi?

Tags: mahabharata, rishi, devi-bhagavata-purana

Lately, I was reading the article on Sukha Brahma on Wikipedia. There, it is mentioned that there are two completely different versions of Sukha Brahma's story. One in Mahabharata and the other in Devi Bhagavata Purana. How could there be two completely different versions in two famous Scriptures. Please shed some light on this.

this is the link to the article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuka

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11080/why-is-there-a-huge-difference-regarding-the-liberation-of-parikshit-in-the-maha and also my answer on that: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11080/why-is-there-a-huge-difference-regarding-the-liberation-of-parikshit-in-the-maha/17009#17009

Comment: Devi Bhagawata is considered medieval Purana by many scholars, so the Mahabharata version should be genuine.

Comment: Human beings procreate by copulation. [Drona](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drona#Birth_and_Early_Life), [Vyasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vyasa#Early_Life), Shuka they all had human parents. There are no magic [ayonija](http://spokensanskrit.de/index.php?beginning=0+&tinput=+ayonija&trans=Translate) births. When scriptures say something that goes against the laws of nature, they need to be rejected using the various [pramanas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pramana#Hinduism).

Comment: @sv - Whoa! Sweeping generalisations much? One must understand the following:- 1. Science is still very much evolving. In fact, advanced scientists agree that all of it is up for grabs. 2. Science in its current form cannot explain everything 3. Therefore, if one encounters something that is beyond the grasp of one's limited scientific/rational outlook, one must realise it is the limitation of said outlook/understanding rather than the falsity of the phenomenon itself. 4. Trying to use B to judge A which is beyond the boundary of B is as unscientific as it gets. 1/2

Comment: @sv 5. There are laws of nature that are beyond the world's understanding because the boundary of nature is beyond what the world has perceived thusfar. 2/2

Comment: @moonstar2001 "scientists agree that all of it is up for grabs" - that's a sweeping generalisation too. No, not all of it is up for grabs. Satellites orbiting earth don't fall to earth every other day because they follow gravitational laws. GPS satellites function so well because they take into account Einstein's general relativity theory. On the other hand, outside of Hindu scripture, there are no miraculous births reported in the past 2000 years. You can read Śuka's birth story [here](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c024.htm) in the Shanti parva...

Comment: @moonstar2001 ...Śuka means parrot. Now I don't understand how can Vyasa have amorous feelings for a "she parrot". A lot of Shanti parva is interpolated so there's lot of fiction in there.

Comment: @sv It was an apsara by name GRtAci. She took the form of a parrot.

Answer (score 2):

The second story seems more reasonable because Shuka's forefathers did not adopt Sanyasa. Vyasa , Parashara and their forefathers were householders.

Secondly, in the present time, we see many brahmins of the "Parashara" gotra. Especially in the Northern India. This means that they were descendants of Sri Shuka Deva.  As Parashara has one son Vyasa and Vyasa had only one son Shuka so it is more reasonable that Sri Shuka would have carried forward the family lineage of the Parashara Vamsha.