# The Mahabharata we have today belongs to which Kalpa?

Tags: mahabharata, bhagavata-purana

The story of Parikshit and Suka in the Srimad Krishna Bhagavatam is different from that of the Mahabharata. This has made people use the argument of Kalpa Bheda that the Mahabharata occurred in a different Kalpa. Now, the Srimad Bhagavatam states it was written in the present Kalpa:

> “parimāṇaṁ ca kālasya kalpa-lakṣaṇa-vigraham |
>   yathā purastād vyākhyāsye pādmaṃ kalpamatho śṛṇu ||” (SB 2:10:47)
>
> Translation: O King, I shall in due course explain the measurement of time in its gross and subtle features with the specific symptoms of each, but for the present let me explain unto you the **Pādma-kalpa (i.e. the Svetavaraha Kalpa)**.

Does the Mahabharata state in which Kalpa it was written?

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11080/why-is-there-a-huge-difference-regarding-the-liberation-of-parikshit-in-the-maha?rq=1

Comment: Padma Kalpa is not Swetavaraha Kalpa.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Its not? But Prabhupada says it is.

Comment: @TheDestroyer This is Prabhupada's purport to Srimad Bhagavatam 2.10.47: The present duration of a kalpa of Brahmā is called the Varāha-kalpa or Śvetavarāha-kalpa because the incarnation of the Lord as Varāha took place during the creation of Brahmā, who was born on the lotus coming out of the abdomen of Viṣṇu. Therefore this Varāha-kalpa is also called Pādma-kalpa, and this is testified by ācāryas like Jīva Gosvāmī as well as Viśvanātha Cakravartī Ṭhākura in pursuance of the first commentator, Svāmī Śrīdhara. So there is no contradiction between the Varāha and the Pādma-kalpa of Brahmā.

Comment: No. There are not. Looks like [some Acharyas](https://prabhupadabooks.com/sb/2/10/47) believe both Kalpas are one. "Varāha-kalpa is also called Pādma-kalpa, and this is testified by ācāryas like Jīva Gosvāmī as well as Viśvanātha Cakravartī Ṭhākura in pursuance of the first commentator, Svāmī Śrīdhara. So there is no contradiction between the Varāha and the Pādma-kalpa of Brahmā." It would be interesting to know their arguments.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Gaudiya acharyas believe but they are also puzzled in solving SB 3.11.34 -37 with this logic..bcz verses say Lord Brahma's 1st Pardha got over at the end of Padma Kalpa..and Varah is first kalpa of 2nd Pardha...Kurma Purana and Markandeya Purana also in sync with this as described [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29170/12304)...

Comment: You should add 'mythology' tag because you are talking about kalpas and kalpa-bheda which have nothing do with history.

Comment: Title and the last line 'Does the Mahabharata state in which Kalpa it was written?' mean two different things. Do you want a direct reference from Mahabharata only? If yes, title needs to be corrected.