# How much time has been passed of current Brahma's life span?

Tags: brahma, time, life-span

I heard from one of my friends that half of current Brahma's time is passed, is that true?

How much time has been passed of current Brahma?

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21446/is-each-of-the-18-mahapurans-related-to-a-different-kalpa - related!

Comment: @kirunal  Welcome to HSE. You can refer the section how to ask questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### I heard from one of my friends that half of current Brahma's time is passed, is that true?

Yes, that's true as per **Chapter 46 of Markandeya Purana** and **Chapter 5 of Kurma Purana**.

### How much time has been passed of current Brahma's life span?

As per [Chapter 46 of Markandeya Purana](https://archive.org/stream/in.ernet.dli.2015.188841/2015.188841.Markandeya-Purana#page/n267/mode/1up),

> 42. For a **hundred** of his (Brahma's) years is denominated a **Para**; and a **Parardha** or **half a Para** is well-known to be composed of **fifty** years.
> 43. So then **a Parardha of his life has elapsed**, O brahman; at the close of which occurred the Maha-kalpa, which is famed as the Padma.
> 44. Of the second Parardha which is now passing, O brahman, the first kalpa (or cycle) ordained is this one called the Varaha.

Sanskrit verses and Hindi translation of Chapter 46 of Markandeya Purana can be found [here](https://archive.org/stream/markandeyapurana/markandeya_purana_hindi#page/n182/mode/1up).

Lord Brahma's life-span is mentioned hundred (100) years (in which day is known as [Kalpa](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6696/1-kalpa-of-brahma)). Lord Brahma's 100 years are known as **Para** which is his life span.

And **Parardha** or **half a Para** is of fifty (50) such years. In another words, Lord Brahma's life-span is of 2 Parardhas.

And at the end of Padma Kalpa (previous Kalpa), first Parardha got over i.e. half life span of Lord Brahma got completed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes we are in the 2nd part of Lord Brahma's lifetime as evidenced by the well known sankalpam mantra

> 'adya brahmanah **dvitiye parardhe** shveta varaha kalpe '.