# Is each of the 18 Mahapurans related to a different Kalpa?

Tags: puranas, bhagavata-purana, brahma, shiva-purana, vishnu-purana

While researching for an answer I came across the reference of **Padma Puran** having been revealed in the **Padma Kalpa** which was the last day of the 50th year of Brahma. Currently we are in the [Varah Kalpa](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp037.htm) or the 1st day of the 51st year of Brahma.

**Is there such a mention for other Purans as well and if yes can someone share the entire list?**

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11077/3500), different Puranas were revealed during onset of different Kalpas.

[**Chapter 53 of Matsya Purana**](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/23267/25F_Chapter_53_1.pdf) mentions Kalpas of all Puranas except **Brahma and Markandeya Puranas**.

> - Padma Purana                        - Padma Kalpa (hence the name)
> - Vishnu Purana                       - Varaha Kalpa (current Kalpa)
> - Vayu Purana (includes Shiva Purana) - Sveta Kalpa
> - Bhagavata Purana                    - Sarsvata Kalpa
> - Naradiya Purana                     - Brhat Kalpa
> - Agni Purana                         - Isana Kalpa
> - Bhavishya Purana                    - Aghora Kalpa
> - Brahma Vaivarata Purana             - Rathantara Kalpa
> - Linga Purana                        - Agneya Kalpa
> - Varaha Purana                       - Manava Kalpa
> - Skanda Purana                       - Satpurusha Kalpa
> - Vamana Purana                       - Kurma Kalpa
> - Kurma Purana                        - Lakshmi Kalpa
> - Matsya Purana                       - Vaivastara Manvantara of Varaha Kalpa
> - Brahmanda Purana                    - Future Kalpas (No specific name mentioned)

Comment: Can I add more details in this answer?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury what details?

Comment: The 2 Bhagavatams and in which kalpa they belong to

Comment: The Bhagavatam you mentioned was the Devi Bhagavatam.

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury It's better not to add those details. I added what Matsya Purana said. You can add it as other answer (maybe Partial answer).

Comment: So my question is whatever is told in those Puranas relative to only those Kalpa?