# Is there any statement from scriptures that has been proved false in all possible interpretations?

Tags: scripture, science, interpretation

Although there are some questions on our site regarding this line, I found no question that is asking directly for such a statement.

Is there any statement from scriptures of Sanathan dharma that has been disproved by *modern science of any form*, without any ambiguity, in all possible interpretations?

Note that the answer should consider all possible interpretations of the scriptural statement and it needs to be false in all such interpretations. I mean there should be no valid interpretation that can be true. So, please refrain from statements or opinions that have been given by atheists or others who may consider only some interpretations.

Comment: But for it, we need modern science to absolutely true. But it is known that we can't absolute sure about so many things. Maybe Only thing we can sure is I exists, I think therefore I am, and many scriptures talk about self realisation. Other so many things can't absolute known to certain in first place, as to absolutely disprove or proved false.

Comment: @HareKrishna yeah, you told truth. Science is developed on some assumptions. There is a possibility that the assumptions may be dependent on several other factors.

Comment: Read chapter 20, 22, 24 in this link to bhagavatam - https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/5/  It contains description of earth, solar system, stars, planets, which do not apply to our present universe. I am not writing this as an answer, because someone can innovatively interpret it as applying to a universe of the past or some other universe.

Comment: @person https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21446/is-each-of-the-18-mahapurans-related-to-a-different-kalpa