# Is Vishnu Puran the only correct puran for our time?

Tags: shiva, vishnu, shiva-purana, vishnu-purana

I came across this video on TRS Clips by Ranveer Allahbadia where the guest says the reason why our Purans contradict each other so much (for example claiming different Supreme Gods) is because they were written for different Kalpas (extremely long time periods), some are for the past and some are for the future. They all are true for their respective own kalpas, but for our time Vishnu Puran is the most relevant one, for it was written in this Kalpa.

If yes then what is the proof of it? How can we know that Vishnu Puran is the one for this Kalpa.

Watch from around 7:50 if you don't wanna watch it completely.

https://youtu.be/soiDhzKDiH8?si=PM6RoaI3TxIvdGfP

Comment: Who said Vishnu Purana is only authentic for this Yuga?

Comment: There's nothing like that- Viṣṇu Purāṇa is the only prāmāṇya Purāṇa for our timeline. If that was the case, there wouldn't be any need of a Vyāsa in every Dvāparayuga compiling the Purāṇas. All the mahāpurāṇas are prāmāṇya for our timeline, it's just some of the events in kathās can be bit different due to kalpabheda, and due to different types of kalpas (sāttvika, etc.), there are Purāṇas of different guṇas too, which venerate Brahmā, Śiva, etc.

Comment: Different Purāṇas were revealed w.r.t different kalpas, which you can check [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/21446/24460), but it's not that only the Purāṇa revealed w.r.t the current kalpa (we're in) is the only prāmāṇya one and others aren't . @Haridasa

Comment: @Bingming yes sir!

Comment: Btw @Bingming if you have time please answer, https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/58679/women-in-dharmashastras there is still a few things I am confused on.

Answer (score 1):

Matsya Purana Chapter 53.:

> 16. The Vişnu Purana. Similarly, the rules of virtue laid down by Parāśara, for the period when there was the Varaha incarnation of Vişņu, in the beginning of Varaha Kalpa, form the Vişnu Purana.
> 17. That Purana contains 23,000 slokas and one who gives it away in charity, along with a cow and clarified butter, in the month of Aşädhas, on the full-moon day, is purified of all sins and goes and rests in peace in the region of Varuņa.
> 18. The Vayu Purana. The rules of virtue laid down by Vayu, along with the glory of Rudra, in the Śveta-kalpa, is known as Vāyavīya Purāņa. It contains 24,000 slokas.
> 19. One who gives it away in charity, along with a cow, jaggery and an ox, to a Brāhmaņa, whose family is large, on the 15th day of light half of the month of Śrăvaņa, attains the region of Śiva and resides there for a Kalpa.

But,Just because a purana belongs to a particular kalpa doesn't mean that in that Kalpa one should just read that puran only. There's no scriptural base for this.

All the Puranas depends on Mahabharata and one can get all benifits of 18 puranas. Basically, Mahabharata is the summary of all the 18 puranas.

MBH.:

> 1:01:67-71.: “Then the greatly glorious Vyasa, addressing Brahma Parameshthi, said, “O divine Brahma, by me a poem hath been composed which is greatly respected. **The mystery of the Veda, and what other subjects have been explained by me; the various rituals of the Upanishads with the Angas; the compilation of the Puranas and history formed by me and named after the three divisions of time, past, present, and future; the determination of the nature of decay, fear, disease, existence, and non-existence, a description of creeds and of the various modes of life; rule for the four castes, and the import of all the Puranas”.**
>
> 1:02:380.: “O ye Brahmana, as the four kinds of creatures (viviparous, oviparous, born of hot moisture and vegetables) are dependent on space for their existence, **so the Puranas depend upon this history (Mahabharata)”.**
>
> 18:06:97.: **“One devoted to Vishnu acquires (through reading this Mahabharata) that merit which is acquired by listening to the eighteen Puranas. There is no doubt in this”.**

I hope this clarifies all your queries. Prd..

Comment: Delightful answer !!

Comment: Thank You. ..