# Women in Dharmashastras

Tags: dharma, dharma-shastras, women, adharma

Why are men continually considered the head of the household in Dharmashastras. I don't mean to be rude and in old times it was far more efficient to have it this way due to the nature of work itself. But, in today's time work is based simply on education to get the most well-paying job. If Dharma is based on the well-paying, then shouldn't the person with the highest education be allowed to work and the other focus on household duties. Now to be clear I love some parts of the Dharmashastras like how woman should never be independent, due to most women usually being weaker than most when biologically speaking it is good to have a family member who looks after her. Secondly, in the law part of Manu, it states how women are fickle-minded, in nature. While this may have been true for the majority in olden times, such sterotypes are harmful and can lead to prejudice views. Now keep in mind I see a lot of good on Manu. I think the division of society based on common man, employer, governor, and intellectual leads to great efficiency in society as a whole and we can see similiar divisions today. I also understand in the past, due to the fact work was more physically demanding it was better for a women to do more household and domestic work and the man to commit time to making money. However, I want someone to put these two main points at rest for me, on the basis of a new opinion or perspective. Also if you want to clarify if anything I said is incorrect please do so.