# Are there sources other than this Mahabharata verse where Shri Veda Vyas is told to be reincarnation of Sage Apantaratamas?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata, adi-shankaracharya, brahma-sutras, vyasa

In Brahma Sutra Bhashya of Shri Shankaracharya, while writing Bhashya for 3.3.32

Acharya says

> apAntaratamo nAma muniH kali-dvApara-sandhau vyAsatvena sambabhUva
>
> A sage named 'apAntaratamas' incarnated in the confluence of Kali and
> dvApara yugas with the name / position of 'vyAsa'.

I found this verse of Mahabharata in support of above statement

[Mahabharata, Shanthi Parva, Section 337, Verse 53-57](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/unic/mbh12_sa.html)

[image]

English Translation. (Note: The chapter number is different because of different editions)

[Mahabharata, Shanthi Parva, Section CCCL (350)](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12c049.htm)

> Having said these words unto the Rishi Apantaratamas, otherwise called
> by the name of Saraswat, the Supreme Lord dismissed him, saying unto
> him.--Go. I am he that was born as Apantaratamas through the command
> of Hari. Once more have I taken birth as the celebrated
> Krishna-Dwaipayana, a delighter of the race of Vasishtha. 2 I have
> thus told you, my dear disciples, the circumstances, of my own former
> birth which was due to the grace of Narayana in so much that I was a
> very portion of Narayana himself. Ye foremost of intelligent persons,
> I underwent, in days of yore, the austerest penances, with the aid of
> the highest abstraction of the mind. Ye sons, moved by my great
> affection for yourselves that are devoted to me with reverence, I have
> told you everything relating to what you wished to know from me, viz.,
> my first birth in days of remote antiquity and that other birth
> subsequent to it (viz., the present one)!"

Does this information regarding Shri Veda Vyas being a reincarnation of Sage Apantaratamas mentioned anywhere else other than the above passage whether in Mahabharata or any other ancient scriptures?

Comment: @GIRIBLR Any idea??

Comment: I think Adi Shankara refers to this again in one of the upanishad bhashya, maybe Mundaka upanishad. https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/compilation/puranic-encyclopaedia/d/doc241402.html

Comment: @GIRIBLR If you can please write a small answer so that the bounty will not go waste.

Comment: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-taittiriya-upanishad/d/doc79848.html

Comment: @hanugm That link just refers back to brahma sutra bhashya ?

Comment: @GIRIBLR  ha. It has the mention, so, I shared.

Comment: @GIRIBLR And I did not go deeper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apāntaratamas meaning apa+antara+tamas i.e., one who is free from all internal darkness is popular in Indian scriptures. He is mentioned in the seventh skanda of the Subala Upanishad and in the Adhyatma Upanishad etc. However, the fact he took rebirth as Sage Vyasa is mentioned directly only in the 3.3.32 of the Brahma Sutra Bhasya of Adi Shankara and Chapter 17 - (Mahābhārata 12.337.1-69) (popularly known as the [Narayaniya](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/223485), a text of 1006 verses occurring in the Shantiparva of the Mahabharata).

Sage Apantaratamas, who was born when Lord Vishnu uttered the syllable "Bhu", reincarnated as Vyasa at Vishnu's behest.

**Mbh.12.349.23388**

> In obedience to this command of the Supreme Lord from whose Speech the
> Rishi Apantaratamas sprang into existence, the latter, in the Kalpa
> named after the Self-born Manu, distributed and arranged the Vedas.

**Mbh.12.349.23418-20**

> Having said these words unto the Rishi Apantaratamas, otherwise called
> by the name of Saraswat, the Supreme Lord dismissed him, saying unto
> him, I am he that was born as Apantaratamas through the command of
> Hari. Once more I have taken birth as the celebrated
> Krishna-Dwaipayana, a delighter of the race of Vasishtha.

The [puranic encyclopedia](https://archive.org/details/puranicencyclopa00maniuoft), considered an authority for all names, says that this fact is also mentioned in the shankara bhashya of the mundaka Upanishad but I am unable to find it.

Just as a side note, it is quite accepted that the great sage Apāntaratamas took rebirth as Sage Vyasa as it is frequently asked by the purvapakshin as to why jnanis and sages take rebirth and Adi Shankara’s commentary of the Brahma sutra bhasya is cited.

Comment: If he took rebirth, then about Srimad Bhagavatam saying that he was an incarnation of Vishnu?

Comment: @Archit There are lot of differences between mahabharata and srimad bhagavatam. So it is difficult to say. For example, see the life of parikshit in both these books. They differ quite a lot. See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11080/why-is-there-a-huge-difference-regarding-the-liberation-of-parikshit-in-the-maha

Comment: okay thanks have seen this question :(. Up in the question the Mahabharata quotes: ‘ was due to the grace of Narayana in so much **that I was a very portion of Narayana himself**’. Been a fan of your answers off late.

Comment: @Archit Thank you very much for your kind words.