# Will Lord Surya Die?

Tags: surya, pralaya

If the Sun loses fuel, does that correspond to Surya the Sun god getting old?  If the Sun burns out, does that correspond to Surya dying?  What does Hindu scripture have to say on the subject of Surya getting old or dying?

Comment: Lord Surya's (all Devas) life span is one Manvantara.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Surya is ParaBrahma. How can He die. Even if He leaves His physical coil. But the Surya is actually Burning out of fuel. So how is ParaBrahma captured inside some atoms.

Comment: Yes. Surya is ParaBrahma in Saura Tradition. But even in Saura tradition there are higher Surya and lesser surya just like how Shaivas consider different hierarchies of Shiva (SadaShiva to Kailasa Shankara).

Comment: Where did you learn that after 5 billion years sun will be exhausted? Add it.

Comment: @SreeCharan No.

Comment: @SreeCharan See [The Sun as a red giant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_giant#The_Sun_as_a_red_giant). Most likely Earth will also disappear around that time.

Comment: Considering that the current Sun was formed from an earlier supernova, there must have been several more Suns before our current one.

Comment: @sv. Oh! I was not aware of this.  Thanks for the link. As this question is about scientific speculation, it would be more apt on space exploration.SE. What do you think?

Comment: @SreeCharan I've mixed feelings on such Q's. If this is closed we also have to close: [How could octogenarian heroes fight in Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3298/2995)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Vedas mention Sun or Lord Surya as the inner soul of everything. So, needless to say there is no question of that eternal Sun (mentioned in Vedas) ever dying.

> **Surya AtmA** jagatah tasthushah cha.
>
> .............
>
> **The Sun is the soul of all** that is dynamic and static.
>
> **Atharva Veda Samhita, KAnda 13, Sukta 2, Mantra 35.**

Comment: But if Surya is eternal, then why is He getting depleted every single half of a second. Where is eternity here

Comment: @AnuragSingh Oh is he getting so? I think this mantra talks about the spiritual sun..in any case Veda mantras are difficult to interpret.

Comment: Then why are we asked to water the Sun. Why is it said that Lord Surya comes everyday to give light, et cetera

Comment: @AnuragSingh This surya which the mantra mentions is obviously Lord surya more than the physical sun we see in the sky.. So, going by the mantra the answer to ur Q is no as i have stated.